# MediaWiki configuring TemplateStyles to include Module:Message box/ambox.css

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have exported Template:Notice from mediawiki.org and imported it into my MediaWiki instance.

On MediaWiki, Template:Notice has this at the top:

[image]

My instance looks like this:

[image]

I have been told that there is a way to configure Extension:TemplateStyles to include additional stylesheets like  Module:Message box/ambox.css to fix this.  How does one do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the styles are on this page, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Module:Message_box/ambox.css
Some options:

- You could just add its css content to your MediaWiki:Common.css page
- You could create another css page by changing the content model of the page you wish to use to css, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:ChangeContentModel first change the content model and then create the page, for example `your_css_page.css` after you can use Extension:TemplateStyles like so `<templatestyles src="your_css_page.css">`

Comment: Specifically the content model should be Sanitised CSS.